# Can't access listbox1 from within a Class Method

Tags: c#

What can i do to access listbox1 from the Class Method? I'm trying to learn C#, and i don't want to leave this behind unsolved. Thanks!

```
    //Classes
    public class Animal
    {
        public  string name;
        public int age;
        public int count;

        //Class Contructors
        public Animal() //Default Constructor
        {
            name = "Oz";
            age = 6;
            count ++;
        }
        public Animal(string _name, int _age)
        {
            name = _name;
            age = _age;
        }

        //Class Methods
        public void Print()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name: " + name);
            listbox1.......
        }
    }
```

**Update : Added the Designer.cs code** at request. Don't know what more details to add, but it won't let me post without this.

```
    namespace CSharpExamples
{
partial class Form1
{
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.btnMethods = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.btnClasses = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();

        this.btnMethods.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.btnMethods.Name = "btnMethods";
        this.btnMethods.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 23);
        this.btnMethods.TabIndex = 0;
        this.btnMethods.Text = "Methods";
        this.btnMethods.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnMethods.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnMethods_Click);

        this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(404, 12);
        this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(182, 238);
        this.listBox1.TabIndex = 1;

        this.btnClasses.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 41);
        this.btnClasses.Name = "btnClasses";
        this.btnClasses.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 23);
        this.btnClasses.TabIndex = 2;
        this.btnClasses.Text = "Classes";
        this.btnClasses.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.btnClasses.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClasses_Click_1);

        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(598, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnClasses);
        this.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.btnMethods);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnMethods;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClasses;
}
}
```

Comment: could you please post also your UI code? thanks

Comment: How are you using the `Animal` class? are you creating instance of it from the event handlers of the form?

Comment: You should have another Form1 partial class (form1.cs?) that has the code that executes for the controls on the form (btnMethods, for example). That would show us information we need to see.

Comment: I was doing this tutorial and instead of **Console Application** i did it in **Winforms**. In Console App i can do `Console.WriteLine(name);` from within the Print Class Method. But in Winforms i get compilation error if i try accessing `listbox1.Items.Add(name)`. I'm new with C# and i wanted to know why.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `listBox1` from the `Animal` class which won't know what it is and will give a compiler error. If you just want the list box to show the names you could try something like this:

```
class Animal
{
    public string name { get; set; } //make these properties. 
    public int age { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }

    //Class Contructors
    public Animal() //Default Constructor
    {
        name = "Oz";
        age = 6;
        count++;
    }
    public Animal(string _name, int _age)
    {
        name = _name;
        age = _age;
    }

    //Class Methods
    public void Print()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Name: " + name);
    }
}
```

Then on your main form you can create a new Animal and then add it to your list using the name:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Animal an = new Animal();
    listBox1.Items.Add(an.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not fully understanding the purpose of this, I may be way off base here. But you could include the `using System.Windows.Forms;` in your class so that you can add a listbox parameter to your Print method.

```
public void Print(ListBox lb)
{
    lb.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Then in your form where the listbox resides you could pass it on

```
Animal pet = new Animal();
pet.Print(listBox1);
```

However the reason I'm not getting this is that I feel you would be better off overriding the .ToString() method to display what you want but add the object itself to the listbox. This way upon selection of an item in the list you can gain access to all the properties you defined for Animal.

so instead of public void print you could use

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return name;
}
```

Then in your form you would just add the instance of animal to the listbox

```
Animal pet = new Animal("Fido", 3);
listBox1.Items.Add(pet)
```

Now your listbox shows Fido but holds the value 3 also

then by simply casting the SelectedItem back to an Animal you gain access to the age property and any other properties you decide to add.

Also, is there a reason why you're not using properties instead of fields for name, age and count?